# How to update C# version in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I have installed C# extensions, my .NET framework is updated, I just can't fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have found the fix and I hope this will help someone in the future.

1. Find your `.csproj` file.
2. Change LangVersion property to desired version.

[image]

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>7</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: What if I don't have it?

Comment: If you don't have it there, just append it to the `<PropertyGroup>` section. Try changing the language version value and see the behaviour. It does work.

Answer (score 5):

**In vs code**
Go to the .csproj file and change

```
         <LangVersion>4.0</LangVersion>
```

to any version you want eg. `<LangVersion>7.2</LangVersion>`

**In Visual Studio**

Right-click on the project node in Solution Explorer and select Properties.

Select the Build tab and select the Advanced button.

In language version dropdown, select any version you want.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I am not using Visual Studio, I am using Visual Studio Code, those are 2 different things.

Comment: I have found the fix and posted the solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change it for only one project, you can edit the project's .csproj file (as other answers here show):

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>7</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

But if you have multiple projects in your solution, and want it changed for all, you need to do the following:

1. Create a file named: "Directory.Build.props" in the root of the solution.
2. Add the following to that file:

> ```
> <Project>
>  <PropertyGroup>
>    <LangVersion>9.0</LangVersion>
>  </PropertyGroup>
> </Project>
> ```

Official documentation is [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version)