# Can't compile my C# code, I don't know what the problem is. New to programming

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors

Sorry I'm very new to programming. I'm trying to compile my first ever program but it's not working. I'm getting these errors:

> "PETOWNER.cs(139,34): error CS1513: } expected
>
> PETOWNER.cs(178,24): error CS1518: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
>
> PETOWNER.cs(225,25): error CS1518: Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct
>
> PETOWNER.cs(230,1): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected"

This is the code in question:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;

namespace joppes_djurfamilj
{
    class PETOWNER
    {
        public string namePETOWNER = "Joppe";
        public int age { get; set; }

        List<ANIMAL> Animal_list = new List<ANIMAL>
        {
            new DOG(3, "Benjamin", "Pork", "Chihuahua"),
            new DOG(2, "Robert", "Pork", "Terrier"),
            new CAT(2, "Kenzo", "Mice", "Tuxedo"),
            new PUPPY(0, "Bertil", "Dogtreats", "Poodle", 10),
            new CAT(1, "Alice", "Fish", "Norwegian Forestcat"),
            new DOG(5, "Plopski", "Pork", "Corgie"),
            new PUPPY(0, "Jimmy", "Dogtreats", "English Mastiff", 6)
        };

        public PETOWNER(int age)
        {
            age = 25;
        }

        public void List_animals()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("These are Joppe's animals:\n");

            foreach (var ANIMAL in Animal_list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ANIMAL);
            }
        }

        // här väljer man vilket husdjur man vill leka med.
        public void Play()
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Which animal do you want to play with?\n");
            int i = 1;

            foreach (var ANIMAL in Animal_list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i + " - " + ANIMAL);
                i++;
            }

            Console.Write("\nChoose a pet to play with from this list: ");

            int Answer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if (Answer == 1)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Joppe is playing with {0}", Animal_list[0]);
                Animal_list[0].Interact();
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Clear();
                Menu();
            }
            else if (Answer == 2)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Joppe is playing with {0}", Animal_list[1]);
                Animal_list[1].Interact();
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Clear();
                Menu();
            }
            else if (Answer == 3)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Joppe is playing with {0}", Animal_list[2]);
                Animal_list[2].Interact();
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Clear();
                Menu();
            }
            else if (Answer == 4)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Joppe is playing with {0}", Animal_list[3]);
                Animal_list[3].Interact();
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Clear();
                Menu();
            }
            else if (Answer == 5)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Joppe is playing with {0}", Animal_list[4]);
                Animal_list[4].Interact();
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Clear();
                Menu();
            }
            else if (Answer == 6)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Joppe is playing with {0}", Animal_list[5]);
                Animal_list[5].Interact();
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Clear();
                Menu();
            }
            else if (Answer == 7)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Joppe is playing with {0}", Animal_list[6]);
                Animal_list[6].Interact();
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue");
                Console.ReadLine();
                Console.Clear();
                Menu();
            }
        }

        //Metod som väljer en husdjur samt olika sorts mat som man matar till valfri husdjur.
        public virtual void Feed()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Which animal do you want to feed?");
            int i = 1;

            foreach (var ANIMAL in Animal_list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i + " - " + ANIMAL);
                i++;
            }

            int answer = 0;

            try
            {
                answer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You must choose a pet from one of the numbers.");
            }

            Food_Menu(answer - 1); **<-----------------// ERROR HERE**

            void Food_Menu(int animal)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("What do you want to feed {0}?", Animal_list[animal]);
                Console.WriteLine("1 - Fish");
                Console.WriteLine("2 - Mice");
                Console.WriteLine("3 - Dogtreats");
                Console.WriteLine("4 - Pork");

                try
                {
                    answer = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You must choose a pet from one of these numbers.");
                }

                if ((answer == 4 && animal == 0) || 
                    (answer == 4 && animal == 1) ||
                    (answer == 4 && animal == 5) ||
                    (answer == 3 && animal == 3) ||
                    (answer == 3 && animal == 6) ||
                    (answer == 1 && animal == 4) ||
                    (answer == 2 && animal == 2))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Animal_list[animal] + " loves the food they received and gets full and full of energy.");
                    Animal_list[animal].Eat();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(Animal_list[animal] + " didn't like the food they received, they barely touch their food.");
                    Animal_list[animal].Hungry_animal();
                }

                Console.WriteLine("\nPress any button to return to the menu.");
                Console.ReadKey();
                Menu();
            }
        }

        //Menyn för programmet
        public virtual void Menu() ***<-----------------// ERROR HERE***
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Welcome to {0}'s family of pets", namePETOWNER);
                Console.WriteLine("[L] List of pets\n" +
                                  "[P] Play fetch\n" +
                                  "[F] Feed a pet\n" +
                                  "[Q] Quit\n");
                ConsoleKeyInfo readKey = Console.ReadKey(true);

                switch (readKey.Key)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.L:
                        {
                            Console.Clear();
                            List_animals();
                            Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to continue");
                            Console.ReadKey();
                            break;
                        }

                    case ConsoleKey.P:
                        {
                            Console.Clear();
                            Play();
                            Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to continue");
                            Console.ReadKey();
                            break;
                        }

                    case ConsoleKey.F:
                        {
                            Console.Clear();
                            Feed();
                            Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to continue");
                            Console.ReadKey();
                            break;
                        }

                    case ConsoleKey.Q:
                        {
                            Console.Clear();
                            Environment.Exit(0);
                            break;
                        }
                }
            }
            
        }

        public override string ToString() **<-----------------// ERROR HERE**
        {
            return String.Format("Joppe"); 
        }
    }
} ***<----------------- ERROR HERE***
```

Comment: If you double-click the error entry, it will bring you to the position of the error. If you look at your code in Visual Studio, it will highlight matching pairs of `()`, `{}` and `[]` in different colors. You can also highlight one bracket/parens and press `<ctrl>+]` and the cursor will jump to its matching mate

Comment: You cannot have function within function. Looks like you have added "Food_Menu(int animal)" method within "Feed()" method.

Comment: You have a local function. Are you using a C# version that supports local functions?

Comment: @Bhavikms, [local functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions) were added in C# 7.0. Not sure how VS Code works with regards to language version but that code would require C# 7.0 or later.

Comment: It looks like that whole series if `if...elsif` in `Play` is unnecessary. Everything is exactly the same each time except the list index. You only need that code once and use `Answer - 1` as the index. Also, you only need to index the list once and assign the result to a variable, then use that multiple times.

Comment: @John hey, how do i get a C# version that supports local functions?

Comment: @Flydog57 hi, my curly brackets arent in red colors in my IDE, its only giving me error when im trying to compile it.

Comment: I didn't know how VS Code handled the language version so I used a search engine. You know that you can do that too, right? Apparently, it's the same as in big VS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52457487/how-to-update-c-sharp-version-in-visual-studio-code. There may be some way to set the default language version in VS Code but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: `error CS1518: Expected class...` / `CS1022: Type or namespace...` Above this line, the compiler thinks you have too many `}` and therefore you have completed the class definition / namespace. Probably because of the first error. The compiler thinks you missed a '}', so from then on it has assumed there really was one.